# $x^3 \frac{dy}{dx} = y^3 +y^2\sqrt{y^2 - x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve : $x^3 \frac{dy}{dx} = y^3 +y^2\sqrt{y^2 - x^2}$

My try :

[image]

But it is not integrable

Comment: What you did looks correct so far. **Hint:** You can try letting $v = \sec u$ or let $v = \dfrac{u^2+1}{2u}$ and proceed with the integral.

Comment: Please include the text of the image using MathJax.

Comment: Try $ y= \sec t , x= \tan t $

Answer (score 4):

$$x^3\frac{dy}{dx}=y^3+y^2\sqrt{y^2-x^2}$$
let $\frac{y}{x}=v$ so $\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$

so:
$$\int\frac{1}{x}dx=\int\frac{1}{v^3+v^2\sqrt{v^2-1}-v}dv$$
now using $v=\sec(u)$ we get:
$$\ln|x|+C=\int\frac{\tan(u)\sec(u)}{\sec^2(u)+\sec(u)\tan(u)-\sec(u)}du$$